# From the data the growth of tumor spheroids determine doubling time using Mathematica and by hand

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, least-squares, mathematica

Task:
From the data the growth of tumor spheroids determine doubling time
[Link to the data](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxsb3Zyb3NocnxneDo3ZWI4MTdiY2U5Mjk4NmRi).
My idea was to use least squares method and Mathematica to helps me find result. But I think that this is nonlinear problem so I will have to use nonlinear least squares method but I don't know how to start. Also I have a question how does my result change if I add some data or throw away.

Comment: Hint: If the growth of $s_t$ is exponential, how does $\log s_t$ behaves?

Answer (score 1):

I put (approximately) your data into Minitab statistical software:

```
T:    4.6      5.7      6.7      7.9      8.8      9.8     11.0     12.0     12.9     15.2
V: 0.0016   0.0032   0.0056   0.0119   0.0202   0.0275   0.0345   0.0661   0.0783   0.1550
```

@Did's hint to take the log of Volume works fine. (It doesn't
matter whether natural logs or base 10.) Here is a plot of the
data with Volume on a log scale (original numbers shown, scale
distorted appropriately). The header shows the regression equation.
The dotted band shows 95% prediction intervals for V at each T.
Roughly, R-sq = 97.2% means that 97% of the variability in $\log_{10}V$
can be explained by regression on $T.$

[image]

However, notice that the residuals towards the center tend to be
positive, while those at the extremes of T tend to be negative.
That suggests that a slight improvement might be made by using $T^2$
as a second predictor variable. Results below. By eye, this looks a little
better, and `R-Sq(adj)` is a little larger. You could use one of the
usual criteria for a formal test whether the quadratic regression is a *statistically
significant* improvement (for your *exact* data). If your *only* purpose
is to find doubling time, then the quadratic regression makes that a little
more complicated.

[image]

Notes: (1) Based on what I see here, I can't imagine why you would want to 'throw away'
any of your data, except possibly the observation at $T = 11.$ Throwing away  points might result in a loss of precision. (2) A quadratic fit to $V$ (instead
of $\log V$) is pretty good.